# Update Query to update backend Tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a split database. In the front end I have an Update Query that used to update the tables with data. Now that I split the database to front end, back end, the table doesn't get updated when I run the query. Is there any way that I can get this query to work again?

Here is the SQL I am currently using:

```sql
UPDATE CWRRR SET CWRRR.status = "Unprocessed", CWRRR.type = "CW RRR"
WHERE (((IsNull([status]))<>False) AND ((IsNull([type]))<>False));
```

There is no error message when I run the query.  It just doesn't work properly. It says it is updating 0 records, which is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure, because if I go into the forms and makes changes or add records it sends it to the Tables, but the queries used for the tables don't send the updates. Also no, I cannot make changes to the Tables in datasheet view because they are linked.

Comment: `UPDATE CWRRR SET CWRRR.status = "Unprocessed", CWRRR.type = "CW RRR"
WHERE (((IsNull([status]))<>False) AND ((IsNull([type]))<>False));`

This is the SQL I am currently using. And there is no error message, it's just doesn't work properly. It says it is pasting 0 records, which is wrong.

Comment: That number varies. It depends on how many new rows were pasted into the table and are blank. On this one over 3000 new rows were pasted and needing to be updated but it can be as small as 1 row.